# Trying to import an audio file in my java application: misplaced construct(s)

Tags: java, audio, user-interface, applet

I have followed an tutorial on importing a wav file into an application. I do not know if I have placed the file URL in the right place :

```
public class Audioapp extends JApplet
{
    public class Sound // Holds one audio file
    {
        private AudioClip song; // Sound player
        private URL songPath; // Sound path
        Sound(String filename)
        {
            try
            {
                songPath = new           URL(getCodeBase(G:\Uni\Programming\Rolling assignements\Week0\Programming week21),filename); // Get the Sound URL
                song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
            }
            catch(Exception e){} // Satisfy the catch
        }
        public void playSound()
        {
            song.loop(); // Play
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
     tokens"

Where would I place the URL, also as I want this to play from the specific workplace folder and not my usb stick, would I just put the name of the file instead of the whole path. I have tried both but they don't work.

any help?

thanks

Comment: What is the error you get? Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I think `getCodeBase()` method takes `String` as parameter. You forget double quotes mark on file path.. ;)

Comment: As iwawiwi said try `songPath = new URL(getCodeBase("G:/Uni/Programming/Rolling assignements/Week0/Programming week21"),filename);`

Comment: thanks guys ^ but im getting this error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"   

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of \ you would have to use \\ or / since single \ is special character in String. See my previous comment.

Comment: @dhali read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not noticing at first glance..

- First: The URL needs a String as constructor argument, not what you have done  (notice the double quotes around the argument. Also, it would help to see the getCodeBase() function too )
- Second: as you seem to be fairly inexperienced, it is wise to memorize that the `\` character, the backslash is often used to escape characters, so in most cases, when used in String constants, it has to be escaped, by doubling it up.

  `songPath = new URL(getCodeBase("G:\\Uni\\Programming\\Rolling assignements\\Week0\\Programming week21"),filename);`

Even better would be to use the `File.separator` static field...

Also, for having an empty "satisfy the catch" block in there, if I were your colleague, I'd hit you with a heavy object, while shouting obscenities at you. Use `e.printStackTrace()`, or a proper logging framework. Teachers won't usually hit you for this, but can give you bad marks...

Comment: LOL i'd totally deserve it mate! thanks for your help, i'll learn..... slowly... :)